# How can I make an element disappear when clicking away from it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I can get the navigation menu to appear when I click on the button, but I can't make it disappear.

Here's the code:

```
const navButton = document.getElementById("nav-btn");
const menu = document.getElementById("nav-menu");
const all = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

const menuActive = () => {
    if (menu.style.display = "none") {
        menu.style.display = "block";
    }
}

const menuDeactive = () => {
    if (menu.style.display = "block") {
        menu.style.display = "none";
    }
}

navButton.addEventListener("click", menuActive);

all.addEventListener("click", menuDeactive);
```

Comment: Multiple issues: `all.addEventListener` doesn’t make sense. See [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](/q/10693845/4642212). `if (menu.style.display = "none")` doesn’t make sense. See [What is the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what is `===`? (Single, double, and triple equals)](/q/11871616/4642212).

Comment: Checking CSS properties directly is [best avoided](/q/55071684/4642212). Instead, a CSS class should be used, e.g. `.hidden { display: none; }`; then [`.classList.contains("hidden")`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check for its existence, `.classList.toggle("hidden")`, etc. Consider using the [`hidden` attribute](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) instead.

Comment: You will have to stop propagation of the event too. Else, when you will click on nav-menu, it will propagate till body and trigger the event there too.

Comment: And finally: see [How do I detect a click outside an element?](/q/152975/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to compare.

Also, `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` is redundant. There can only be one `body` tag.

```js
const navButton = document.getElementById("nav-btn");
const menu = document.getElementById("nav-menu");
const all = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

const menuActive = () => {
    if (menu.style.display == "none") {
        menu.style.display = "block";
    }
}

const menuDeactive = () => {
    if (menu.style.display == "block") {
        menu.style.display = "none";
    }
}

navButton.addEventListener("click", menuActive);

document.body.addEventListener("click", menuDeactive);
```

Comment: If I use ==, it won't work.

Comment: also, adding document.body.addEventListener causes it not to work. Even when i take off the const all line.